# I'm very new to react and I am having issues with adding a new file

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

This is my app.js file. I was trying to add another file called `Align.js`. I tried to import it here but it was not working. I kept getting a syntax error. There is probably a lot wrong with this.

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header.js';
import './App.css';
import Mainimage from './Mainimage.js';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Mainimage />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What are the `issues` you facing?

Comment: I tried to add another file called Align.js that had some jsx stuff in it. I tried importing it to this app.js file but I kept getting errors. im not too sure what i did wrong but it could be the code i was using (reg. html).

Comment: Did you export your component in Align.js ? Also how are you importing, show us your syntax.

Comment: here is the align.js file syntax. Mind you I am very new to react and all of this is probably wrong:

Comment: import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Align extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
 
    );
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export your component in order to import it into another

**Align.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Align extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Align">
       Align Component
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Align;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Header from './Header.js';

import './App.css';

import Mainimage from './Mainimage.js';

import Align from './Align';  // .js is optional, should already be handled by bundler

class App extends Component {
  render() {

    return (

      <div className="App">

        <Header />
        <Mainimage />
        <Align/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: With the caveat that normally you don't include the extension in the import statement.